# Get createdby attribute value from js

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I need get createdby attribute value from js. But when I try get like this:

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdby").getValue()`

Creates an error - this field not exist on the form.
Can I get this attribute value?

Comment: Where is the `form` ?

Comment: Place this field on form and then your code will work... if you want you can make this filed as hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Add the `Created By` field to the form, as mentioned by Yaqub in the comments. You can set the field to not be visible, if you prefer. Afterwards you will be able to fetch the field using `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdby").getValue()`.
- If you do not want to add a (hidden) field to the form, you could fetch the record from the OData endpoint using [`SDK.REST.retrieveRecord`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427(v=crm.7).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The field must be on the page in order to use Xrm.Page

Once you've added it to the page, you can use this to get both the id and name of the "createdby" field.

```js
getLookup = function (f) {
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute(f)) {
        if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute(f).getValue() != null) {
            return Xrm.Page.getAttribute(f).getValue()[0];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log(f + " is missing from the page.");
        return null;
    }
}

//Usage
var createdbyLookup = getLookup("createdby");
if (createdbyLookup != null) {
    var creatorId = createdbyLookup.id;
    var creatorName = createdbyLookup.name;
}
```